# Парсинг с изменением ссылки

Tags: python, парсер, telegram-bot

Хочу написать программу, которая бы парсила сайт wooordhunt.ru и выдавала бы транскрипцию, например с помощью телеграм бота. Я знаю как передавать информацию в бот, но мне непонятно как правильно парсить целый сайт - раньше я занимался отдельными страницами.

Я заметил, что ссылка на искомое слово имеет следующий вид: wooordhunt.ru/слово, соответственно, при инпуте пользователя необходимо будет парсить конкретно эту страницу. С помощью каких инструментов лучше реализовать такой парсер?

Comment: Для парсинга веб страницы можно использовать библиотеку BeautifulSoup. Если посмотреть на структуру например страницы со словом [help](https://wooordhunt.ru/word/help) можно увидеть, что транскрипция находится по пути (Full XPath) __/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]__, по этому пути можно и получать транскрипцию.